# The entity type 'IdentityUser' is part of a hierarchy, but does not have a discriminator value configured

Tags: mysql, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, mysql-connector

I'm trying to migrate a .NET Core 1.1 MVC-application using EntityFrameworkCore (1.0.1) from SQLite (`"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite": "1.0.1"`) to MySQL (`"MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore": "7.0.6-IR31"`).

My context is extending `IdentityDbContext`, and when running `Database.EnsureCreated()`, using Sqlite, the AspNet-tables (RoleClaims, Roles, Users, etc) were automatically configured.

With the MySQL-connector, when i attempt to run either `Update-Database` or `Database.EnsureCreated()`, I get the error:

`The entity type 'IdentityUser' is part of a hierarchy, but does not have a discriminator value configured.`

Should I really configure this manually, and if so, how?

Context:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{

    //DbSets here..

    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {

    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);

        builder.Entity<IdentityUser>()
            .HasDiscriminator<int>("Type")
            .HasValue<ApplicationUser>(1);
    }
}
```

ApplicationUser:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string Firstname { get; set; }
    public string Lastname { get; set; }
    public string Firmname { get; set; }
    public string CVR { get; set; }
    public string ATT { get; set; }
    public string Telephone { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Show your identity models (usually called ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext, etc). You either have base and derived class in your dbcontext or maybe you used the wrong base class

Comment: @Tseng I've updated my post.

Comment: Let me just clarify - with SQLite I had everything working and the AspNet-tables were generated and usable. I've changed nothing in my context, except add the discriminator in OnModelCreating, which it was complaining about, although in SQLite it automatically added the Discriminator-column, and set all users to "ApplicationUser" in that column. Could you elaborate "You either have base and derived class in your dbcontext"? @Tseng

Comment: I suspect you may have `DbSet<IdentityUser>` **and** `DbSet<ApplicationUser>` in your context, but I can't see it, as this would could cause such an error, because your code only adds a discriminator for the base class (IdentityUser) but not for ApplicationUser. And Oracles MySQL Provider is not one of the best/most polished ones and still in development and (at least) official mysql provider would complain if you don't register the base class too (i.e. add `.HasValue<IdentityUser>(0)` to your code above

Comment: You also may want to open an issue on the MySQL/Oracles official bug tracker if you feel it should work other way: http://bugs.mysql.com

Comment: I don't have any DbSets with users manually defined - when extending IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>, I get a DbSet<ApplicationUser> called Users. Should I consider another DBMS than MySQL for Core? If so, which one is most stable at the moment?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/ for a list of providers. Postresql was available during early rc1 releases, so it should do fine (npgsql) or one of the alternative (paid or free) mysql providers if you really **have too**. But first you can try adding `.HasValue<IdentityUser>(0)` and see if it works

Comment: @Tseng it worked (although other errors occoured) - could you answer this post with some information about this? Why do you need to add the base-class as well?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131724/discussion-between-jeppe-rask-and-tseng).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It seems that the MySQL Provider for EntityFramework Core doesn't automatically do registrations for derived classes (which other providers do implicitly), which is why you need to specify the discriminators in code.

However, since `IdentityUser` is not an abstract class, it can in theory be instantiated and assigned too and the MySQL Database Provider requires a registration for it too (even if in production there will never be an value with this discriminator).

So you have to register the base class too.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(builder);

    builder.Entity<IdentityUser>()
        .HasDiscriminator<int>("Type")
        .HasValue<IdentityUser>(0)
        .HasValue<ApplicationUser>(1);
}
```

Comment: Your comment about 'abstract' class made me realize I forgot to mark my base class as such.  Thanks.

Comment: Same here. Oops.

Comment: Although my code now works, I have two problems. First, I get an error about "Type" column not existing, so I just changed it to Id, which is in my model (real column called RecId). But the second and bigger problem is now the context doesn't return anything.

Comment: When you add an discriminator, you also need to perform an migration so EF Core will create a new migration thats adds the column to your database tables